# Bootstrap accordion behaving weird

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The product specs portion is behaving correctly. When I click on group 1 it shows, the when i click on group 2 it will minimize group 1 and show group 2.

The problem is the next two categories, Usage and Installation and Care aren't doing the hole accordion thing. If I click on group 1 and then group 2 it maximizes both, it won't minimize group 1 like ti should.

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <!--Product Specs-->
    <hr>
    <h3 style="text-align: left;">Product Specs</h3>
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active ">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
          <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOneSpecs" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOneSpecs">
                  Collapsible Group Item #1
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOneSpecs" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Group #1 information
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwoSpecs" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwoSpecs">
                  Collapsible Group Item #2
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwoSpecs" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Group #2 information
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThreeSpecs" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThreeSpecs">
                  Collapsible Group Item #3
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThreeSpecs" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Group #3 information
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--END of Product Specs

    <!--Usage-->
    <hr>
    <h3 style="text-align: left;">Usage</h3>
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active ">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
          <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOneUsage" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOneUsage">
                  Collapsible Group Item #1
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOneUsage" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOneUsage">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Group #1 information
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwoUsage" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwoUsage">
                  Collapsible Group Item #2
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwoUsage" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwoUsage">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Group #2 information
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThreeUsage" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThreeUsage">
                  Collapsible Group Item #3
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThreeUsage" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThreeUsage">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Group #3 information
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End of Usage-->

    <!--Installation and care-->
    <hr>
    <h3 style="text-align: left;">Installation & Care</h3>
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active ">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
          <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOneCare" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOneCare">
                  Collapsible Group Item #1
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOneCare" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOneCare">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Group #1 information
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwoCare" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwoCare">
                  Collapsible Group Item #2
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwoCare" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwoCare">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Group #2 information
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThreeCare" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThreeCare">
                  Collapsible Group Item #3
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThreeCare" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThreeCare">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Group #3 information
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--END of Installation & Care-->
```

When I click on anything in group 2 and three. It will minimize group 1?

jfiddle Link [jfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/13263/)

Comment: Please, post your jsfiddle.

Comment: added the jfiddle @alirezasafian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```html
<div class="tab-content">
                            <!--Product Specs-->
                            <hr>
                            <h3 style="text-align: left;">Product Specs</h3>
                            <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active ">
                                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                                  <div class="panel panel-info">
                                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                                        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOneSpecs" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOneSpecs">
                                          Collapsible Group Item #1
                                        </a>
                                      </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseOneSpecs" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                                      <div class="panel-body">
                                        Group #1 information
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="panel panel-info">
                                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                                        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwoSpecs" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwoSpecs">
                                          Collapsible Group Item #2
                                        </a>
                                      </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseTwoSpecs" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                                      <div class="panel-body">
                                        Group #2 information
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="panel panel-info">
                                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                                        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThreeSpecs" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThreeSpecs">
                                          Collapsible Group Item #3
                                        </a>
                                      </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseThreeSpecs" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                                      <div class="panel-body">
                                        Group #3 information
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--END of Product Specs

                            <!--Usage-->
                            <hr>
                            <h3 style="text-align: left;">Usage</h3>
                            <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active ">
                                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                                  <div class="panel panel-info">
                                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                                        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOneUsage" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOneUsage">
                                          Collapsible Group Item #1
                                        </a>
                                      </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseOneUsage" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOneUsage">
                                      <div class="panel-body">
                                        Group #1 information
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="panel panel-info">
                                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                                        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseTwoUsage" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwoUsage">
                                          Collapsible Group Item #2
                                        </a>
                                      </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseTwoUsage" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwoUsage">
                                      <div class="panel-body">
                                        Group #2 information
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="panel panel-info">
                                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                                        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseThreeUsage" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThreeUsage">
                                          Collapsible Group Item #3
                                        </a>
                                      </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseThreeUsage" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThreeUsage">
                                      <div class="panel-body">
                                        Group #3 information
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--End of Usage-->

                            <!--Installation and care-->
                            <hr>
                            <h3 style="text-align: left;">Installation & Care</h3>
                            <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active ">
                                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                                  <div class="panel panel-info">
                                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                                        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOneCare" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOneCare">
                                          Collapsible Group Item #1
                                        </a>
                                      </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseOneCare" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOneCare">
                                      <div class="panel-body">
                                        Group #1 information
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="panel panel-info">
                                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                                        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwoCare" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwoCare">
                                          Collapsible Group Item #2
                                        </a>
                                      </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseTwoCare" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwoCare">
                                      <div class="panel-body">
                                        Group #2 information
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="panel panel-info">
                                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                                        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThreeCare" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThreeCare">
                                          Collapsible Group Item #3
                                        </a>
                                      </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseThreeCare" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThreeCare">
                                      <div class="panel-body">
                                        Group #3 information
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
       

    <!--END of Installation & Care-->
```

Comment: That worked can you please instruct me as to what you did?

Comment: I modified the id=accordion for group 2 and 3. you will see that the group 2 now have the accordion1 as the id and group2 has accordion2. I also had to change the data-parent= for the respective panels

Answer (score 0):

All your panel-group have the same id

try changing the id=accordion to id=accordion1, id=accordion2 and id=accordion3

Comment: that removed the problemw hen  i click no anything in group 2 it his group 1, however group 2 and 3 still wont for example wont close question when when question 3 is clicked.